# How can I visualize a frequency as square wave?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to get a typical square wave of a 16MHz and 50Hz signal withing a y-range of 0 to 1.

[image]

My code is:

```
hz[period_] := 1/period
Plot[SquareWave[{0, 1}, hz[x]], {x, 0, 3}, Exclusions -> None]
```

and has the following result.

[image]

What do I have to modify in my code in order to get that square wave form, shown above ?

Comment: Search `SquareWave[ ]` in the docs

Comment: Take care with how you've defined the independent variable in the `SquareWave` function. What you essentially have is $S(\frac{1}{x})$ (where $S$ is a square wave function) but you most likely want something like $S(50x)$ and $S(16\times 10^6 x)$.

Comment: The rapid fluctuation near the origin is something of a clue that inverting the plot variable is probably not what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[.5 (1 + SquareWave[2 π (16 10^6) t]), 
{t, 0, 10^(-7)},
ExclusionsStyle -> Dotted]
```

and

```
Plot[.5 (1 + SquareWave[2 π 50 t]), 
{t, 0, .01},
ExclusionsStyle -> Dotted]
```

Comment: What is the reason for the 2Pi in the equation and the 10^(-7) and .01 in the t definition ?

Comment: Why does Mathematica plots a strange diagram by editing the t range from .01 to 1 e.g. {t,0,1} ?

Comment: @Jorgos:  `Sin[ ]` goes through one cycle when its argument goes through $2 \pi$.  The $10^{-7}$ is a range where the structure of your function is visible.  If you change the range in the second figure to `{t, 0, 1}`, you get so many cycles of the square that they cannot be rendered well.